# NativeScript Vue - Material Design Icons not showing

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, nativescript, nativescript-vue

In assets/fonts, I have `materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf` and in assets/css, I have `materialdesignicons.css`. And finally in `main.js`, I have the following:

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';

TNSFontIcon.debug = true;
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'mdi': './assets/css/materialdesignicons.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();

Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon);
```

And I am using icon like the following:

```
<Label class="mdi" :text="'mdi-youtube' | fonticon" style="color: #fff;font-size: 40px;" />
```

However, icons are not showing at all.

[image: Screenshot from 2019-03-10 18-23-18]

Btw, I grabbed the css from https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign-Webfont/tree/master/css.

Please help!

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined the font family, can you share the definition of `mdi` class in your CSS?

Comment: https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign-Webfont/blob/master/css/materialdesignicons.css -> It was already defined here.

Comment: If I should define `mdi`, then how should I define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines to your CSS,

```
.mdi {
  font-family: "Material Design Icons", "materialdesignicons-webfont";
}
```

Basically the postscript name, font file name in your project. Also you must use `fonts` directory not `assets/fonts`, by default the files under `fonts` directory are only automatically registered upon app launch.